# Check if object exist

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I saw many code that began like that

```
var a=a||{};
```

Now I know that its check if a exist.

My question is why to check it if its at the first of the code?

I mean the programmer know that a is not exist.

Comment: In case `a` exist, use the existing `a` object instead of creating new. You won't know whether the script included may create such variable - and you may mess up the other script by overwriting it.

Comment: It actually tests if `a` has a falsy value, but if `a` is undefined, as in _not declared_, it won't work, you'd have to use `typeof a !== 'undefined'`

Comment: Yes I know it but as I said this is at the first of the code so the programmer know that a is not exist

Comment: `a` it's a extremely simple example but all that does is check if the namespace is already created. The library could be included from another library for example, and developer won't know if that happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The programmer *should* know if the variable exists or not.

It's used to mash different pieces of script together without having to keep track of which part of the script is loaded first. Several scripts will have the same piece of code at the start, so they share the same variable.

For the first script, the variable is declared, and there is no previous value for it, so the `{}` value is used.

For the following scripts that use it, the `var` is ignored as the variable is already declared, and the previously set value of the variable is used.

Of course, declaring the same variable in several places has a code smell to it. Preferrably you should keep track of what you are doing so that you only declare it once.

Answer (score 1):

Translated into clearer code

```
var a; // The variable declaration gets brought up because of hoisting
```

More info on hoisting [here](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting)

```
if( a ) {
    a = a; // if a is a truthy value then assign it to itself
} else {
    a = {}; // if a is a falsy value then set the default to an empty object
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

That's a shortcut to fall back on a default value - {} in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, javascript can be written in multiple files and within each file you can have multiple declarations and functions defined.

Even if the programmer knows for a given instance if the variable exists or not, there is no way to know if it already exists when this code is called from somewhere else.

This should not happen in well written code (all from one developer / house) but it does happen in projects where the js code is amalgumated from multiple places.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) has a very nice answer about variable scopes in javascript, it should clarify your doubts.